# Want to access previous trades data before entering a new data

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api, strategy-pattern

I want to access trades data of last 3 months in pine script before entering a new date , how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strategy.closedtrades` namespace. It has many properties that you can use.

Some examples you can use are:

```
strategy.closedtrades.entry_price
strategy.closedtrades.entry_time
strategy.closedtrades.exit_price
strategy.closedtrades.exit_time
strategy.closedtrades.profit
strategy.closedtrades.size
```

Otherwise you need to keep track of the trades yourself using `var` variables and arrays.